# Not creating file via my browser

Tags: php, file, createfile

when I run my page on my local host it does not create the file. I have given read and write permissions to the folder site. i have used system and exec functions and when i run the page via the terminal it creates a file but via my browser it doesnt.

```
$my_file = '/var/www/site/file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
```

Comment: Did you give permission to the apache user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with a relative adresse?

```
$my_file = 'site/file.txt';
```

Comment: Is threw back this error. `Cannot open file: logstash/file.txt`

Comment: fopen in 'w' mode wont create a file..in 'w+' mode it'll create a file.  
check link http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters

Comment: it creates the file but it only in set it to read. I have used to chmod 777. 
`chmod("/var/www/site/file.txt", 777);
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w+') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); ` and the site folder has `drwxrwxrwx` permissions set.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands will correctly apply permissions to the directory.

```
cd /var/www/site
sudo chmod 664 *
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

If the error persists, please post any PHP errors that are thrown.

Comment: Run `ls -l /var/www/site` and add it to your question